# Unable to use specific version of .net in ubuntu

Tags: .net, ubuntu, installation

Dotnet core installed in Ubuntu 20.04 but unable to run dotnet program

I have Dotnet installed on my local machine (Ubuntu 20.04) but am unable to run anything. The error message is When I run a .cs program, I get the following error saying I Need 6.0.0:
[image]

But at the same folder, I have dotnet installed (both the .NET SDK 7.0.302 and  and .Net runtime 7.0.5) when asked the dotnet --info
[image]

When trying to install 6.0, I gt a message saying "dotnet-install: .NET Core SDK with version '6.0.408' is already installed."
Used this link to install but changed the last command to 6.0: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#scripted-install

I'd really appreciate any help installing this. This is extremely frustrating. Most guides online and questions here ended with installation.

Comment: Did you try downloading and installing from the link the error message gave you instead?  Or maybe changing the app version to 7.0?  The output of dotnet --info says otherwise to 6.0 being installed.

Comment: Yeah, the link had two options: manual and scripted install. I posted the scripted install here. Regardless, .net 6.0 is installed

Comment: If the dotnet binary is not seeing it, I'd suspect something is up with that install.  I'd either remove/reinstall all .NET Core versions or upgrade the app to .NET Core 7, since 7 appears to be working currently.

Comment: Would you mind pasting the material in the images as text using backticks (`\``)?

Comment: @LoverofStructure 

`You must install or update .NET to run this application.
App: /sdk-dotnet-samples/bin/Debug/net6.0/SendTextMessage
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '6.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /snap/dotnet-sdk/205
The following frameworks were found:
  7.0.5 at [/snap/dotnet-sdk/205/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed
To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=6.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.20.04-x64`

Comment: @dylanatwork Could you please edit this into your original post (and delete the comment)?

Answer (score 1):

I resolved this issue with the following link:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-scripted-manual#manual-install

I changed the 7 to a 6.

````
export DOTNET_ROOT=$(pwd)/.dotnet

mkdir -p "$DOTNET_ROOT" && tar zxf "$DOTNET_FILE" -C "$DOTNET_ROOT"

export PATH=$PATH:$DOTNET_ROOT:$DOTNET_ROOT/tools```
````